# How to divide a collection into subgroups in functional programming way?

Tags: python, functional-programming

I'm so confused that how to divide a collection into subgroups in a functional programming manner since this operation depends on other elements in the same collection.

One of these problem is to divide a video clip into several GOP groups.

A video clip can be viewed as a list with different types of frames in it, eg. [IPBBBPBBBIPBIPBPBP], and I, P, B is type of the frame.

A GOP is a sub clip that start with an I frame (though in real world it must be an IDR frame, I simplify the question here a little bit)

So the problem is how to achieve this in a FP way: [IPBBBPBBBIPBIPBPBP] -> [[IPBBBPBBB],[IPB],[IPBPBP]] ?

I have read some FP books and I am so confused how can I use just map, filter and reduce to achieve this.

In Imperative Programming language such as Python I could easily write something like this:

```
gops = []
for frame in video:
    if is_i_frame(frame) is True:
        gops.append([frame])
    else:
        gops[:-1].append(frame)
```

But in Functional Programming world I can't figure out how to do this or how to represent this problem in Lambda Calculus expression.

So I hope someone can show me how to do this in a FP way. Is it possible to do such FP operation in Python ? And how will the Lambda Calculus expression looks like ?

Comment: What ifs the first frame isn't an `I`?

Comment: just to be clear, you want an answer in the flavor of `map/reduce` not that you want an answer that is a "functional" method that someone else could call right?

Comment: @ScottHunter It must be an `I`. It is mandated by all modern video codec standards such as H.264

Comment: @JonSG I just wonder how people handle this kind of problem in functional programming language and more importantly what the lambda calculus will looks like. I use python just to illustrate the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a combinations of `itertools` and `functools` you can get to a fully functional solution. (Though, way longer, and, in my opinion less readable, than the pythonic version you mentioned in your question.)

To break down the steps I am using, first, I am creating an index for which sub-video, each frame belongs to:

```py
import itertools as it
import functools as ft

list(it.accumulate(video, lambda total, frame: total + (frame=="I"), initial=0))
>>> [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

Them, I have to remove the extra 0 at the start, so I use `itertools.islice`:

```py
list(it.islice(
    it.accumulate(video, lambda total, frame: total + (frame=="I"), initial=0), 1, None
))
>>> [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

Then, I will zip the sublist index, with the original `video` array:

```py
zip(
    it.islice(
        it.accumulate(video, lambda total, frame: total + (frame=="I"), initial=0), 1, None
    ),
    video
),
```

Now, the meat of the operation: I will use `itertools.groupby`, to group the elements of `video` by the index we just computed:

```py
it.groupby(
    zip(
        it.islice(
            it.accumulate(video, lambda total, frame: total + (frame=="I"), initial=0), 1, None
        ),
        video
    ),
    key=lambda x: x[0]
)
```

The group by will return an object that looks like `[[(1,I), (1,P),...], [(2,I),...], ...]`, so we want to reduce that to proper strings, so we can use `functools.reduce`, and map it over all the groups:

```py
list(map(
    lambda k_g: ft.reduce(lambda total, x: total+x[1], k_g[1], ""),
    it.groupby(
        zip(
            it.islice(
                it.accumulate(video, lambda total, frame: total + (frame=="I"), initial=0), 1, None
            ),
            video
        ),
        key=lambda x: x[0]
    )
))
>>> ['IPBBBPBBB', 'IPB', 'IPBPBP']
```

Notice that, I used `(frame=="I")`, but you can very well replace this with more advanced logic `is_i_frame` for instance, as long as it returns a boolean.

Answer (score 1):

The `functools` package provides a `reduce` we can use. We can use it to append the "next" item to the last sub-list in our accumulator.

```py
from functools import reduce

data = list("IPBBBPBBBIPBIPBPBP")

def fn(acc, item):
    if not acc or item == "I":
        acc.append([])
    acc[-1].append(item)
    return acc

print(reduce(fn, data, []))
```

That will give you:

```
[
    ['I', 'P', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'P', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
    ['I', 'P', 'B'],
    ['I', 'P', 'B', 'P', 'B', 'P']
]
```

Comment: A quick fix is to just change the condition to `if not acc or item == "I"`.

Answer (score 0):

Is this FP enough for you?

```
def framify(clip,gops=[],gop=''):
    return gops + [gop] if clip=="" else framify(clip[1:],gops if gop=='' else gops+[gop],'I') if is_i_frame(clip[0]) else framify(clip[1:],gops,gop+clip[0])
```